# O365 JS web add-in: BCC fetcher erroring on Outlook for Mac

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

Our Outlook Add-in relies on the BCC getter and setter. I have a screenshot of a user with an empty BCC field trying to make an action that requires BCC and the api (Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.getAsync) is returning an error whose message reads:

```
Operation failed because the data is not current on the server.
```

We aren't doing anything special to access it. With ES6:

```
const getBCC = () =>
   q.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       Office.context.mailbox.item.bcc.getAsync(({ value, status, error }) => (
          status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded ? resolve(value) : reject(error)
       ));
   });
```

At least 200 of our users have experienced this error. They are all Outlook for Mac users. Can someone explain why fetching an empty (or populated!) BCC field would generate this error, and if there's anything we can suggest to our users to avoid it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Can you please add some code to show how you're using `bcc.getAsync`?

Comment: Sure - updated.

Comment: Thanks for raising it. we are working towards fixing it. Meanwhile could you please try opening another compose window and run the API's and see if that works.

Comment: This issue is now fixed and will be available in the next week insider fast release.